# PHP form unable to update database

Tags: php

Hi guys I'm having trouble with my PHP code. Unable to update the database when I submit the form. I'm trying to update the new price.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if(! $db )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$price = $_POST['price'];

$sql = "UPDATE bookprice ".
       "SET price = price " ;

mysqli_select_db('books');
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $db );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated Price successfully\n";
mysqli_close($db);
}
else
{
?>
```

Form code:

```
<form method="post">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update Price">
<input name="price" type="text" id="price">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Still in the process of grasping PHP. Any form of help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has any of the answers helped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the `$price` variable to set the `price` column to.

Use `"SET price = $price " ;`

or inside quotes `"SET price = '$price' " ;`

What you're doing right now is ***"set the price column equals price column"*** instead of the intended value taken from the POST variable `$price`. More on this at the end of my answer under **Footnotes**.

Another thing:

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $db );
```

you need to reverse the query and DB connection:

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
```

In `mysqli_`, the connection comes first, then the query's variable.

Plus, use:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','books');
```

You're using all four parameters in your DB connection, ***so you can drop:***

```
mysqli_select_db('books');
```

since you're not doing anything with it, and simply add `books` as the DB's parameter.

Using the fourth parameter with the DB's name, is the same as using `mysqli_select_db` with the DB's name and connection variable, which is something you are not using.

- Read the manual **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php**

---

You also have a missing closing brace in

```
else
{
?>
```

if you don't have anything after that, do:

```
else
{ 
  echo "Fail";
}

?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

If your price contains a dollar sign, or a dot or mix of those, or something else that SQL does not agree with (*which am under the impression it could*), you will need to wrap it in quotes:

```
$sql = "UPDATE bookprice SET price = '$price' " ;
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE bookprice SET price = '".$price."' " ;
```

If your column is an `int` type, then you can use

```
$sql = "UPDATE bookprice " . "SET price = ".$price;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

remove @

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
```

and update the query

```
$sql = "UPDATE bookprice ".
       "SET price = ".$price ;
```

Comment: How about escaping the external input before using it in an SQL query? Ever heard of SQL injection?

Comment: Please edit your post to provide an explanation of what your code is doing and why it will solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
if($_POST['update']){
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX'); // remove '@'

    if(!$db){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db)); // Needs the database connection
    }

    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $sql = "UPDATE `bookprice` SET `price` = '$price'"; // Use the variable $price

    // mysqli_select_db('books'); // This should already be set in the new mysqli();
    $retval = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // Turn this around;
    if(!$retval) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($db)); // needs the database connection
    } else {
        echo "Updated Price successfully\r\n"; // \r\n will always work \r or \n alone will not always work
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
}
else {
    echo 'There was no post';
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update Price">
            <input name="price" type="text" id="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php (since you are working with a price this may come in handy)

You should also consider the use of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` so:

```
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['price']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually if you concat your queries with $parameter directly, it opens up a security risk
$price = $_GET["price"] (from the URL) 
$price = $_POST["price"] (from the FORM Post)

UPDATE `bookprice` SET `price` = '$price'

You should try using prepared statements like

Update bookrprice set price = :price
or
Update bookrprice set price  = ?

and then create a associate key value pairs to security and pass it in to your query. This is why it is not recommend to use mysql_query and rather mysqli or PDO methods.

then your would pair the above statement by

execute(array(":price"=>$price))

or 
execute(array($price))